# How to make it so there are no duplicates in JavaFX ComboBox

Tags: java, javafx, java-8

In this program, you can add words to the ComboBox using a textfield. How would you make it so the program will not accept any words that are already in the ComboBox? I tried to make it so if the textfield input is equal to something in the ComboBox then it shouldn't add it but it will not work.

```
package gps_destinations_controller;

import gps_destinations_model.Model;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.SingleSelectionModel;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class Controller implements Initializable 
{
    @FXML TextField destinationInput;
    @FXML ComboBox<String> destinationList;
    private SingleSelectionModel<String> selectionModel;

    private Model model;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) 
    {
    model = new Model();

    destinationList.getItems().addAll(model.getDestinations());

    selectionModel = destinationList.getSelectionModel();  

    selectionModel.select(model.getSelectedIndex());
        System.out.println(destinationList.getItems());



    }    

    @FXML protected void addDestination() 
    {
        String input = destinationInput.getText();

         if(!destinationList.getItems().equals(input))
         {
        destinationList.getItems().add(input);
         }


        model.addDestination(input);


        destinationInput.clear();

    }






    @FXML protected void itemSelected( ActionEvent event ) 
    {
    int index = selectionModel.getSelectedIndex();
    model.updateSelection(index);

    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Where is the code that goes with this?

Comment: @Mr00Anderson This is what I have tried and have jsut added the rest of the code if(!destinationList.getItems().equals(input))
         {
        destinationList.getItems().add(input);
         }

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're comparing the `items` list itself to the element you want to add. This always results in `false` and the item is always added. You need to use `contains` to check, if an element is already in the list:

```
if(!destinationList.getItems().contains(input)) {
    destinationList.getItems().add(input);
}
```

Comment: Well that was easier than I thought it would be thanks!